# How to segment ROI using SIFT/SURF

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, image-segmentation

SIFT is used for feature extraction. Most of the tutorials that I have seen out there only show the features detected using SIFT. I need to identify ROI using SIFT. Images look like this but in worse condition (taken from different angles, some are blur, with more texts and numbers in other places too)

[image]

I need to extract this and then perform digit recognition:

[image]

What are the ways to segment this part? I was going for SIFT/SURF but couldn't find any tutorial to segment out the ROI. If there are any other suggestions then please provide the link.

Edit: Images that I have are grayscale

Edit1: this is just an example image I got from Google, My dataset only has grayscale images not colored

Comment: You cannot use SIFT / SURF here because you are not guaranteed to detect any meaningful features within that window of interest.  Feature points are only detected if there are strong second order derivative responses.  The images are quite blurry so you won't get any meaningful SIFT features.  You need to use a dense descriptor instead.  Failing that, use colour features.  Clearly the LCD display has a different colour distribution than the outer housing.  Start simple.

Comment: @rayryeng-ReinstateMonica I have grayscale images - should have stated that earlier

Comment: They are grayscale images because SIFT works only on grayscale images.  The images above are colour.  Don't convert to grayscale?

Comment: @rayryeng-ReinstateMonica this is just an example image I got from Google, My dataset only has grayscale images not colored

Comment: Why did you show images that are not what you're actually using?  Upload your actual images instead.

Comment: Can you guide me to a correct direction @rayryeng-ReinstateMonica?